# require.js compress all template to one template on deployment

Tags: backbone.js

I have set up my application based on this example
http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/
The thing that I now have more than 50 html files. It takes more than 5 seconds to load all files on first load. I know using node.js and require.js I can compress or minify the .js file and .css files but was wonder if there are any way we can compress all html templates into one file to speed up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm about to face this very problem in my project and here's what I plan to do:

1. Write template loader function so that details of how templates are retrieved are encapsulated within.  After that I only have to change one place in code when template handling logic changes.
2. At build time, compile my Handlebars.js templates into JS code.  The process is described [here](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html).
3. Use `R.js` from `require.js` package to build single JS file from all compiled templates.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using templates like described in that article (with require !text, _.template etc), then they will be compressed into JavaScript file as well. Give it a shot.

Comment: yes I am using but I guess when I am specifying templates in the modules I should use the .js instead of .html? I need to read up on that more.

Comment: No you shouldn't use .js instead of .html. Optimizer will inline and load your templates right into _.template call. Try to search your html in compressed file.

Comment: I don't see the document about this. how did you find out?

Comment: I just tried. I didn't find any documentation about this, but i think it would be very useful. You can ask require.js developers on github.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't make sense that 50 html files are loaded simultaneously into the browser, by right the require.js and node.js should be loaded once into the browser. Then ur index.html will select the html file amongst the 50 to append further as its content.

Comment: As you can see in the following example every time you will load both of main.html and list.html. I am still looking for the solution of this problem http://backbonetutorials.com/examples/modular-backbone/

Comment: I tested r.js the tool to optimize require.js project but dont' have any function to make all templates into one file. I wonder how everyone is solving this problem or all the people go with other template system?